# Gatling Pass TestCase ChainBuilder Array["TC01","TC02", ...] dynamically to Scenarios

Tags: java, arrays, scala, gatling

I have written some logic to form a array of Gatling ChainBuilder Testcases as below

```
def getTestCaseArray(rowNumberArray: ArrayBuffer[Int]): ArrayBuffer[ChainBuilder]={
// my logic inside which is working fine.
}

array = genereateTestCaseArray() //
```

This array can hold many TestCase(ChainBuilder) object and I have to inject it at runtime as below ...

```
val scn = scenario ("All test cases for my scenario")
   .exec(array[0], array[1], ... )
```

How can I achive this 
`.exec(array[0], array[1], ... )` dynamically ? as I have no idea how many object can be inside this array.

I have something below in my mind.

```
val scn = scenario ("All test cases for my scenario")
       .exec(Actions.myAction(array) )
```

and

```
  object Actions {
    def myAction(array: Array[String]) = {
     //some logic here which can return me
     // comma separated ChainBuilder objects 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh my goodness, this `exec` guy have it's built in feature, you just have to pass iterator to your array. It will keep iterating for your objects. BOOOM :)

```
val scn = scenario ("All test cases for my scenario")
       .exec(array.iterator)
```